# How To get LastActivity from ejbbered server using smack library?

Tags: android, smack

I am sending below request for getting the LastActivity(Last seen status) of the below user from ejabbered server using smack library in android.

```
try {
    Packet pk = new Packet() {

        @Override
        public String toXML() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return "<iq from='" + Utils.createJabberUserIdByUserId(me.getUserId()) + "'" + " id='last1' "
                    + " to='" + Utils.createJabberUserIdByUserId(friendId) + "' " + " type='get'> "
                    + "<query xmlns='jabber:iq:last'/>" + "</iq>";
        }
    };
    ConnectionManager.getInstance().getXmppConnection().sendPacket(pk);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

Result I got from the server is:

```
 <iq from="272@jabber.com">
     id="last1"
     to="274@jabber.com/64faf3314bee33c4" 
     type="result"
 </iq>
```

But the result should be like this:

```
<iq from='272@jabber.com' 
    id='last1'
    to='274@jabber.com/64faf3314bee33c4'
    type='result'>
  <query xmlns='jabber:iq:last' seconds='903'/>
</iq>
```

What am I doing wrong? please help.

Comment: Which version of aSmack do you use?

Comment: I am using the library in https://github.com/lasalvavida/xabber-jingle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually a sign that there is no provider for the `query`/`jabber:iq:last` extension, if you don't get that child XML of an IQ in Smack. You will have to register a Provider with the Provider Manager.

BTW I recommend using the [offical aSmack version](http://asmack.org), where this would been done automatically for your.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Smack's methods to get the last time-stamp of a user, base on last activity.
Try this:

```
LastActivityManager lastactivity = 
LastActivityManager.getInstanceFor(MyXMPPconnection);
LastActivity result = lastactivity.getLastActivity(JID); // user jid
Log.d("Last seen",result.lastActivity");
```

Which prints a long number in log-cat. You can convert it to Year,Month,Day,Hour and so on.
You can get the exact time-stamp with:

```
long current-millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - result.lastactivity;
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.